# Windows Phone 8.1 Custom Live Tile Template

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create a Live Tile with a different layout that the ones defined in the tile template catalog. Specifically, I want text to appear on top of an image for the 150x150 tile. Is there a way to do this for a Windows 8.1 app? I do not see this template for that size. Thanks

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a custom live tile you have to create image and use it as a background for your live tile.

Take a look at this post: http://spasol.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/creating-custom-live-tiles-for-windows-phone/ the Update Live Tile with custom parameters section.

Additionally If you need to update your live tile using background task you need to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use a template from Windows Phone 8 on 8.1? It does look like ShellTile does what I want, but is not available on 8.1

Comment: What do you mean by ShellTile? There are 3 diffrent Templates for WP8: Flip, Cycle and Iconic. None of them is availiable on WP 8.1 You can use any template from the link you've provided in question or build your custom tile as i mentioned in my answer.